# Divide two Select statements?

Tags: postgresql, divide

I'm new to sql and I'm trying to divide two select statements, but not getting the right answer. I'm getting 70, but the answer should be 9.20% 
What am I doing wrong here?

```
select count(clocked_in_at - starts_at)
from master_shift
where clocked_in_at is not null
and clocked_in_at <> starts_at
and date_part('minute', clocked_in_at - starts_at) > 0
/ 
(select count(id) from master_shift where clocked_in_at is not null)

starts_at                 clocked_in_at
"2015-10-15 18:00:00+00";"2015-10-15 18:15:00+00"
"2015-10-20 17:00:00+00";"2015-10-20 17:00:00+00"
"2015-10-21 20:30:00+00";"2015-10-21 20:30:00+00"
"2015-10-22 20:00:00+00";"2015-10-22 20:00:00+00"
"2015-10-23 17:00:00+00";"2015-10-23 17:00:00+00"
"2015-10-23 20:30:00+00";"2015-10-23 20:30:00+00"
"2015-10-24 18:30:00+00";"2015-10-24 18:30:00+00"
"2015-10-26 17:45:00+00";"2015-10-26 17:45:00+00"
"2015-10-26 20:30:00+00";"2015-10-26 20:30:00+00"
"2015-10-27 15:54:00+00";"2015-10-27 15:54:00+00"
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample data?

Comment: @DarshanMehta - I've added the sample data

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
SELECT 100 * sum(extract(second from (clocked_in_at - starts_at))) / count(id)
FROM master_shift
WHERE clocked_in_at IS NOT NULL
AND clocked_in_at <> starts_at
AND date_part('minute', clocked_in_at - starts_at) > 0;
```

Comment: Or just `AVG(clocked_in_at - starts_at)`.

Comment: @Barmar If every row has an `id` value, then yes. If `id` may be null, then `count(id)` will be smaller than the number of rows.

Comment: I get this: "78:42:19.517143"? looks like it's in time format?

Comment: Ah right. First convert interval to seconds, PG timestamps are in usec. The `extract()` function produced a simple number. See updated answer.

Comment: getting closer! I get this now: 568.088571428572

Comment: So that is in seconds. If you want it in minutes you should do `extract(minute from ...` which should give 9.468.